# getDescribe Failing on Individual Object Id in Tests (Data Protection and Privacy)

Tags: dynamic-soql, describesobject, data-protection-and-privacy

My tests of methods using dynamic SOQL queries stopped working after enabling Data Protection and Privacy. I receive the following Exception:

> FATAL_ERROR caused by: System.SObjectException: Field
>   Lead.IndividualId is inaccessible in this context

The exception is thrown as shown in the following snippet that I use to build the field list part of the query string (it works in production):

```
for (Schema.SObjectField field : leadFieldsMap.values()){ 
    String fieldname;
    Try{fieldname = field.getDescribe().getName(); 
    }
    catch(SObjectException e){
       System.debug('error on field.getDescribe().getName() + e.getMessage() );
    } 
    objFields += fieldname + ','; 
    }
```

When I look at permissions, I have access to the Individual object lookup on Lead and all of the Individual object fields except Id, which isn't listed as a checkbox choice. I tried "seeAllData=true" on the test method as well.

Any thoughts on how to make field.getDescribe().getName() work for IndividualIDs in tests?

---

Update

Solution (not ideal but tests now pass):

```
for (Schema.SObjectField field : leadFieldsMap.values()){ 
    String fieldname;
    Try{ 
        // this fails on lead.individualID in test only. no solution found
        fieldname = field.getDescribe().getName(); 
        fieldList.add(fieldname);
    }
    catch(SObjectException e){
        System.debug('error on field.getDescribe().getName() ' + e.getMessage());
        //ignore exception when in test context only
        if(Test.isRunningTest()){
           continue;
         }           
    }
    objFields += fieldname + ','; //comma separated fieldnames for query
}
```

Hope this saves someone else some time.